# Create a Line chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset which contains 20 columns and millions of rows. The important ones which are required are below:

```
Week Supplier Sales Product Family...... Col20
1     A        10    X
2     B        15    X
3     C        12    X
1     D        11    X
2     E        17    X
```

My task is that I have to create a line chart based on the sum of sales weekly but I have to show only Supplier A, Supplier B, and then all of the rest together. I'm struggling to do this power BI. Any help involving R or Python scripting is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, Created a new column which consisted only the supplier a,b and rest